# Error: AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP (infinite connection interrupted/connection resumed loop)

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

**Description**
We are trying to have our local client devices to connect and communicate with AWS IoT Greengrass V2. Initially everything worked as expected and the communication was just as successful in the local environment. In the greengrass we see client device successfully authenticated and yet in an instant session closed.
TLS channel shutdown by the task-scheduler immediately after host resolution resulting in infinite RECONNECTING <> AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP loop.
SDK connection to the endpoint is never established. TLS opening and closing of sessions at a very fast pace.

**Expected Behavior:**
The mqtt message is published successfully to moquette broker and over to iot core. The basic_discovery.py script in Samples directory is supposed to send 10 messages to core device before it disconnects.

**AWS IOT SDK**

1. Repository Link: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2
2. Version: V1.7.1

Greengrass V2 with Automatic Provisioning Used.

**Platform/OS/Device**
1.OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
2. Greengrass Core Device (Container) : arm64v8/debian:buster base image.
3. Client Device (Container) : arm64v8/debian:buster base image.

**Closely Followed Docs:**

1. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/implementing-local-client-devices-with-aws-iot-greengrass/
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/client-devices-tutorial.html
   3.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/troubleshooting-client-devices.html

**Closedly Followed Issues:**

1. https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2/issues/110
2. https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/issues/191

**Already Tested Approaches:**

1. Changed Timeout from 5 secs to 30 seconds( mqtt_connection).
2. Provided all local addresses 192.168.10.125, 17.17.0.1 etc. Discovery started working properly. Address must be static. (although ip detector feteches it automatically)
3. There has to be no conflict in container communication. (No Conjusted Network: tested on local environment)
4. Possible cause: Duplicate Client Id, either because publish function called again and again or (other device using the same certificates :not possible). ( Created New Thing named TestThing) Remarks: No Effect.
5. Manual Testing using local bash command:
   python3 basic_discovery.py --thing-name VolttronThing --topic test/topic --root-ca ~ /rootCA1.pem --key ~ /private.pem.key --region ap-southeast-1 --cert ~ /certificate.pem.crt --message "hello" --mode "anything"
   Remarks: Same Error.
6. No quotos issue. (max size 128Kb) (testcase: sent hello world through basic_discovery.py. Remarks: Failed)
7. Changed Client ID. Finding Client Id must be Iot Thing Name.
8. Reviewed and Redeployed Authorization and Bridge Policy with wildcards to give extra priviliges.
9. Viewed greengrass logs. Channel inactive error. Means Client Disconnected.
10. Removed GroupDeployment ( multiple deployments conflict) : Remark: No Effect
11. Firewalls disabled. ( no firewalls detected ufw.. disabled, Remarks: No Effect)
12. Change port (moquette) (AWS_IO_SOCKET_CONNECTiON_REFUSED... as default protocol is mqtt, not mqtt over web socket.so we cannot change port from 8883 to something else)
13. Tested on office jetson nano which was working just fine earlier. Remarks: Same Error.
14. Created new TestThing to check certificates issue. Remarks: No Effect
15. Could be that the singapore region is faulty as tested us-west-2 worked just fine. Remarks: Same Error. Hangup
16. Sometimes after connected! message. The cursor hangs up either because it does not see message paramater or the connection is infact hangup.
17. io.moquette.broker.NewNettyMQTTHandler: Unexpected exception while processing MQTT message. Closing Netty channel. CId=VolttronThing. {}
    java.io.IOException: invalid massage
    Remarks: Only received when message size is too large.

Greengrass Logs:

1. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eIBmE3OCiEleDZyvPnWSkEPWWxs1LA0_/view?usp=sharing
2. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qruKd__LglRagQHJb4Htf7jStmFgfO3E/view?usp=sharing

Basic Discovery Logs (client script: Aws-iot-sdk/Samples/basic_discovery.py)

1. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vm14pO7QIqKl5QlOibjs5N61dAlMGA1S/view?usp=sharing

Note: Sometimes even the connection hangup error does not show up and cursor keeps on blinking without sending hello world message to core device.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still relevant: Are you installing Greengrass to a custom location? I had a similar issue when Greengrass didn't have write permissions to its own folder. Changing the permissions either to `ggc_user` or setting write permissions solved it.